# How improve the quality of my question (without answers)

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, low-quality-posts

I would like to understand how to improve the quality of my question:[Doubts on asymptotic criterion for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{a}\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{n^a}\bigg)-e^{1/n}$ with $a>0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4453199/921438) 
Indeed I have received only some comments (without any conclusion), even if I have shown my attempt and I have underlined my doubts and the troubling passages.
Why do you think my question is without an answer?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks ok to me. I think either less people who know what you're asking fluently or general disinterest from dealing with such Qs